How in google spreadsheets =QUERY search item with " in the title
I have QUERY formula
=QUERY('My sheet'!J2:K;"SELECT J WHERE K="""&A1&"""")

it works good if I have item without "  in A1 (for example table, my table, car )
but if i have  item with " my formula gets ERROR (for example "table", my "table", car is "black")
How to modify this formula to make it work with " symbols?
I tried
{regexmatch(=СИМВОЛ(39)&F4&СИМВОЛ(39)


syntax is:
=QUERY('My sheet'!J2:K; "SELECT J WHERE K='"&A1&"'"; )



for CHAR(34):
=QUERY('My sheet'!J2:K; "SELECT J WHERE K='"&""""&A1&""""&"'"; )


=QUERY('My sheet'!J2:K; "SELECT J WHERE K='"&CHAR(34)&A1&CHAR(34)&"'"; )



for CHAR(39):
=QUERY('My sheet'!J2:K; "select Col1 where Col2="""&A1&""""; )


=INDEX(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE('My sheet'!J2:K; "'"; "♥"); 
 "select Col1 where Col2='"&SUBSTITUTE(A1; "'"; "♥")&"'"; ))



or regex out both:
=INDEX(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE('My sheet'!J2:K; "['""""]"; ); 
 "select Col1 where Col2='"&A1&"'"; ))


or reverse:
=QUERY('My sheet'!J2:K; "select Col1 where Col2='"&REGEXREPLACE(A1; "['""""]"; )&"'"; )


